# External monitor not going to sleep

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, sleep, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 5750g, my problem is that when my laptop goes to sleep or shut down, the external monitor keep saying that no input and won't go to sleep mode.
Everytime I have to turn off the monitor.
I am using windows 8.1 Professional
Also, I already tried in BIOS with no luck
Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: what monitor (brand, model) are you using and how is connected? HDMI, DVI, etc?

Comment: LG 22EN33, it is connected via VGA

Comment: Have you installed the display driver? Also according to the manual there is setting for power saving. Did you try to turn that on or off?

Comment: Not yet. I will check it when i'll be home.

Comment: I installed the driver but nothing... Monitor still wont turn off :(

Comment: I tried with another monitor and that monitor isn't turning off too. I'm guessing that it's a BIOS or graphics card problem (Nvidia GT 520m).

Comment: Try this `powercfg.exe -energy`

look at the output report for a device that is not responding to the sleep request